# MaterialBottomNavigation has no animations

Tags: android, xml, android-fragments, bottomnavigationview

My Bottomnavigationbar has no animations when i tap items. I tried changing themes, colors etc. they still don't show up. I want the items to get bigger and show the titles. Normal bottomnavigationbar also has the same issue. Do i need to do this programmatically or is it supposed to animate the items when they are pressed?

BottomNavigation:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout4"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Main">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        layout="@layout/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


    <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
        android:id="@+id/mainFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/btnm"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/toolbar" />

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/btnm"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/mainFragment"
        app:menu="@menu/nav_menu" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Items:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/settings"
        android:title="Settings"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_settings_black_24dp" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/pls"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_storage_black_24dp"
        android:title="Plugins" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/software"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_baseline_home_24"
        android:title="Manage" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/deletepls"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_delete_sweep_black_24dp"
        android:title="Delete plugins" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/consolepage"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_desktop_mac_black_24dp"
        android:title="Console"/>


</menu>
```

Comment: can you show us the Style used for this layout ?